# Getting black overlay when rotating the device from portrait to landscape during navigation

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, autolayout, screen-rotation

The application i am developing which support both portrait and landscape for iPad using autolayout. Issue is when device in Portrait mode i am tapping on button to navigate next screen from current screen.

While navigation action is on immediately i am rotating the device to landscape mode from portrait mode, After navigated to next screen getting black overlay in the right corner like in the reference screen attached.

[image: Black space image]

and this black overlay not getting hide in this screen until i rotating the device to portrait.

**Note:**
1.This issue is happening in both orientation when i am doing the above mentioned action.
2.This issue is happening in some other screens also.

I am using viewWillTransition to set the view orientation

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        popOverLay.isHidden = true
        popOverView.isHidden = true
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.openMapsActionSheet?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

Comment: try, removeFromSuperView ?

Comment: @McDonal_11 can you please elaborate.

Comment: Do u update, Viewcontroller's superview's width size ? anywhere in Coding ?

Comment: Bcos, in ur screenshot, that is Landscape screen..!! But, showing portrait model. So I am asking, did u change view's width anywhere in coding ?

Comment: @McDonal_11 No i didnt set viewcontroller size in coding.

Comment: self.openMapsActionSheet?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) U r dismissingVC ???

Comment: Instead dismissingVC? U may change POPViewController ?? Is the any reason for dismissingVC in both orientation ?

Comment: openMapsActionSheet is an alertcontroller i dismiss the alertcontroller when rotating the device. Even i remove this  self.openMapsActionSheet?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) code. issue is happening.

Comment: In Portrait, that black screen is coming ?

Comment: Try everything removed in that function. Add one by one, u can find. I have tried here, no issues found.

Comment: Yes this issue occurs in both orientation and this issue happen only when i am doing prior action and rotating the device in mean time. For example: When tapping button action to navigate next screen and in the mean time i rotate the device immediately.

Comment: Can u show button action code? Using Segue or Programmatically ? In, normal, orientation is working fine ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165289/discussion-between-ram-mohan-and-mcdonal-11).

Comment: Hi can either of you post the solution please? just an explanation is also nice.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. When there is a map and rotate the device it showing the blank screen at the bottom. Can anyone help me out?